# Laravel's dingo/api with controllers instead of routes

Tags: api, laravel

How can I use Controllers instead of Routes when with dingo/api (https://github.com/dingo/api) package?

The documentation (https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki) uses routes only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dingo is just an extension of the Laravel router, so you can use controllers just like you do in any other Laravel project.

So this:

```
Route::api(['version' => 'v1', 'prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::get('posts', function()
    {
        return Post::all();
    });
});
```

would become:

```
Route::api(['version' => 'v1', 'prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::get('posts', 'PostsController@index');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean connecting a controller to a specific dingo route? like this:

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
```

then followed by

```
$api->version('v1', function($api){
    $api->get('posts', 'PostsController@index');
});
```

But somehow Dingo cannot find the directory of controller, so what I do is start from `App\` directory like this: `App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@index` .

so the correct syntax would be

```
 $api->get('posts', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@index');
```

Comment: Is it possible to just mention the controller name and the method would be automatically applied based on the request type (GET/POST)?